# Determining which number lies in sequence $1234567891011\ldots$ on the $10^{100005}$'th position

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have the infinite sequence made from concatenation of consecutive natural numbers: $123456789101112131415\ldots$ There is also a function $f$, where $f(n)=k$ if the digit on the $10^n$'th position is from natural number with $k$ digits (so for example $f(1)=2$ because on the $10$'th position in the sequence there is $1$ from $10$, which is a 2-digit number.

The problem asks us to find $f(100005)$.

This is a problem from an exam from my discrete math class, yet I don't know which concept should I use. I only covered sums, binomial coefficients, generating functions, Stirling numbers and Inclusion-exclusion principle. I don't see however how any of these concepts are connected to this problem. Any hints?

Comment: Which number or which digit?

Comment: I'm really confused by what the function $f$ does.

Comment: I mis-edited it, assuming he was asking digit, but then saw the question in more detail. @barakmanos

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Then what does the word "position" mean in the context of this question?

Comment: $f(n)=k$ if and only if on the $10^n$'th position in the sequence $123456789101112...$ there is a digit from $k$-digit natural number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the $n^{\rm th}$ digit in the sequence $123456789101112\dots$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626216/find-the-n-rm-th-digit-in-the-sequence-123456789101112-dots)

Comment: this pdf is useful https://myows.com/protects/copyright/67407_mathexploration-pdf

Comment: @Elaqqad: This is similar, but the result asked for is the decade we are in rather than the digit itself.  The same technique works.

Comment: @user46944:   I believe you take the digit in the $10^n$ th position and ask how many digits are in the number it came from.  So for $f(4)$ you ask how many digits are in the the numbers that make of the block containing the $10^4$th digit.  In this case the three digit numbers end at digit $2889$ and the four digit numbers end at digit $38889$, so the $10^4$ digit comes from a four digit number and $f(4)=4$

Comment: @Elaqqad While that is related, I don't think it is a dupplicate.

Answer (score 5):

There are $9$ one digit numbers, which fill the first $9$ positions.  There are $90$ two digit numbers, which fill the next $180$ positions.  There are $900$ three digit numbers, which fill the next $2700$ positions.  The position at the end of the $k$ digit numbers is $\sum_{i=1}^k9i10^i$  You need to sum this series and find the smallest $k$ such that the sum is greater than $10^{100005}$

Answer (score 4):

So, define $g(n)$ to be the number of digits of the number at the $n$th digit of this number.

You are looking for $f(n)=g(10^n)$.

$g(n)=k$ if and only if:

$$1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i(10^{i}-10^{i-1})\leq n < 1+\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(10^i-10^{i-1})$$

So you need a closed form for $$m(k)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{k} i(10^i-10^{i-1})=1+9\sum_{i=1}^k i10^{i-1}$$

It can be shown that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} iz^{i-1} = \frac{(k-1)z^k - kz^{k-1}+1}{(z-1)^2}$$

With $z=10$ this gives $$m(k)=\frac{1}{9}\left((k-1)10^k-k10^{k-1}+10\right)$$

Then you are trying to find the smallest $k$ so that $m(k)>10^{100005}$.

Definitely $k\approx 100000$. You'd have to try some values.

Comment: $(+1)$ But there are some typos: With your definition of $m(k)$, we have $g(n)=k$ iff $m(\color{blue}{k})\le n\lt m(\color{blue}{k+1})$, so we're trying to find the smallest $k$ such that $m(k\color{blue}{\mathbb{+1}})>n=10^{100005}$, which turns out to be $k=100001$ by computerized search. ($m(k)$ is the index of the first digit of the smallest $k$-digit natural number being concatenated, i.e., the index of the $1$ in $10^{k-1}$.)